# Freeware/Opensource Scrum Tool for Project Management

Tags: open-source, project-management, scrum

In your opinion what is the best and most effective scrum opensource or freeware tool?

I am interested in your opinion and I look so forward to manage properly my backlog :-)

Comment: Have you looked into [Ace Project](http://www.aceproject.com/) at all?

Comment: I used a product called [Agilefant](http://agilefant.org/) with great success running scrum with several teams. I liked it because it had just the right number of features to run a scrum team and none of the bloat of most of the other stuff.

Comment: I answered this question in another thread, explaining a solution  using GoogleDocs (including example files) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21853248/826194

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Trello

I currently use [Trello](https://trello.com/) for very simple projects. We also use it for all Stack Exchange planning, from snack to be bought this week to Trello cards with user stories.

Trello basically gives you cards and a virtual board. It's the basics of agile.

## Rally

In the past I've been a very happy user of [Rally](http://www.rallydev.com/) which is totally free for up to 10 users - a good sized team.

Rally gives you stories, burndowns, tasks, sprints, quality and defect tracking.

### Other tools

- [Online Plannning poker](http://www.planningpoker.com/)
- [Collaborative sticky notest](http://listhings.com/) for retrospectives

Comment: Cheers! Trello looks very promising!

Comment: I just gave a try. Seems, Rally includes Trello by creating custom page  with Kanban APP in addition with moreover complete SCRUM. But the community edition is limited especially with only one Project.